# Bash function to alias python command with ipython when no arguments are used

Tags: bash

I would like to alias *python* with *ipython* only when no arguments are follows so that I can use ipython's shell and its autocompletion feature. For example:

```
#This should start the ipython shell
python 

#These should run python as usual
python -c "print(100)" #run print in python
python --version #run python --version
```

I am trying with something like

```
python() {
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; 
then
    ipython
else
    eval $(printf "%q " "python $@")     #python --help: command not found
    #eval $(printf 'python %s\n' "$@")   #infinite loop calling python function
fi
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for the `eval`. This function uses *env* to run the "default" python command

```
function python() {
    if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; 
    then
        ipython
    else
        env python "$@" # will run python wherever it's installed
    fi
}
```

Comment: but then I will get in trouble when changing the default location for python, or when using a virtual environment (or at least I think)

Comment: Edited answer to fix that problem.

Comment: `env python` doesn't do anything that `python` alone doesn't already do. `env` performs path lookup the same way the shell does.